# I can't render datatable with id from controller

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, datatables

The list of users is diplayed in a datatable, in datatables actions i've added a button for each row that leads to another datatable that contains the list of products related to the selected user.

```
public function userProductsList(productDataTable $productDataTable, $id)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->find($id);
        return $productDataTable->with("user_id",$id )->render('users.productsList');
    }
```

The route is: `Route::get('users.productsList/{id}', 'productController@userProductsList')->name('users.productsList');`
the url already contains the id of user but this error is returned instead of displaying the productDadtatable:
**
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: users.productsList] [URI: users.productsList/{id}].**

Answer (score 0):

Your `route` should be like this

```
Route::get('users.productsList/{productDataTable}/{id}', 'productController@userProductsList')->name('users.productsList');
```

Comment: this returns 404